# while loop select option continue looping

Tags: php, mysqli

HI everyone i have a problem this is the [result](http://prntscr.com/2rhtl7)

This is my codes.

```
$iqry2 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT itemname,unitmeasure FROM table_item");

    $iqry2->execute();
    $iqry2->bind_result($itemname,$unitmeasure);
    $iqry2->store_result();


    <div class="form-group ">
    <label for="itemname" class="control-label col-lg-2">Item Name</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">


    <select name="iname" class="form-control">

    <?php

    while ($iqry2->fetch()){

    echo "<option>$itemname</option>";

    ?>
    </select>


    </div>
    </div>


    <select name="unit" class="form-control">

    <?php

    echo  "<option>$brandname</option>";

    }

    ?>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: your question is not clear. Please provide detail info

Comment: Sorry.
This is my question.
why the result on select is one by one?
thanks in advance

Comment: Your brackets are not properly closed so I just can't figure out what your real intention was when writing this code.  Do you really want to close 2 divs per item without opening them, except for the one BEFORE the loop?  Are you sure you want to implement your loops this way, closing a select in each step and then opening the next one?  Let's rethink this code a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have

```
  </select>
  </div>
  </div>
  <select name="unit" class="form-control">
```

Within your while loop, so instead of filling 2 `select` boxes, you continuously close and open new drop-downs.

Change it to:

```
<?php
    $items = array();
    $brands = array();
    // First create 2 arrays with all options
    while ($iqry2->fetch()){
      $items[] = $itemname;
      $brands[] = $brandname;
    }
    $iqry2->close();
?>
<!--Now use those arrays to fill 2 seperate selectboxes-->  

<select name="iname" class="form-control">
<?php foreach($items as $item):?>
    <option><?=$item?></option>
<?php endforeach;?>
</select>


<select name="unit" class="form-control">
<?php foreach($brands as $brand):?>
    <option><?=$brand?></option>
<?php endforeach;?>
</select>
```

Comment: Did you forget  `$items = array();
    $brands = array();` ?  And please post FULL information, you keep giving half info.

Comment: Thanks for.
my error is fixed
thank you..

Comment: my error is
$itemname[] = $itemname;
haha

Answer (score 2):

Are you certain that your query is not returning empty?

You should do a vardump() of the data returned by your query. If it's NULL or FALSE, then you need to modify your query to check if it's empty or not. If not empty, then proceed.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do ? You have 1 or 2 selects ?
You make a while, wich is supposed to push only `<option>`, but in your while you write a `<select>` tag wich is in another select...

```
<select name="iname" class="form-control">
    <?php
        while ($iqry2->fetch()){
            echo "<option>$itemname</option>";
        } // Add this bracket here to finish your while
    ?>
</select>

<select name="unit" class="form-control">
    <?php
        // You need another while here
        while ( ???? ) {
            echo  "<option>$brandname</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

I'm not sure what you wanna do but i think you must do 2 sql requests, one `select itemname...` and then a second for `select brandname`

But reading your code i really don't know what's your expectation :(

Comment: Thanks everyone one for your reply.
i tried two while
the one select is working
but the second while select is not working

`<select name="iname" class="form-control">
    <?php
        while ($iqry2->fetch()){
            echo "<option>$itemname</option>";
        } // Add this bracket here to finish your while
    ?>
</select>

<select name="unit" class="form-control">
    <?php
        // You need another while here
        while ($iqry2->fetch()) {
            echo  "<option>$brandname</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>`

Comment: sorry.
im newbie in php